# insert Usercontrol in FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, flowlayoutpanel

I have a `FlowLayoutPanel` and several `UserControl`s. Now I want one controll to be always at the bottom of my `FlowLayoutPanel`. So I want to add my UserControl just above the lowest controll. Is there an easy way to insert user controls in a `FlowLayoutPanel`?

I'm currently thinking about removing the control at the bottom, and adding the control I want to add and  add the bottom control again. But this I do not think this is really the best way. Is there anyone here who could help me with some information on how to do this ?

Comment: Is it easy to switch from WinForms to WPF, or do I need to learn a lot before you can do that?

Comment: WPF is pretty easy to pick up. For the most part you can use it exactly the same way you use Forms and take on some of it's more complex features as you require them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can set the `Index` of a `Control` OR `User-Control` in `Flow-Layout Panel`.

```
//flPanel is your flow-layout panel...
flPanel.Contorls.Add(ctrl1); //ctrl1 can be any control or user control
flPanel.Contorls.Add(ctrl2); //ctrl2 can be any control or user control
flPanel.Controls.SetChildIndex(ctrl1, flPanel.Controls.GetChildIndex(ctrl2) + 1);
```

This way, your ctrl1 would be at bottom though it was added first into your `Flow-Layout Panel`.

If you have more `Control`s, and you are toggling their visibility in different events, then you will have to set `Index` for each `Control` every time.

I suggest to place your `Control` in `Panel` and add `Panel` in your `Flow-Layout Panel`.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with WinForms/WPF. 
You are trying to use a panel for flowing layout for something that is clearly not meant to use flow.

You should change your layoutpanels accordingly. Try using a flowlayout on the items where you need the flow, then putting that panel inside another panel which also host your bottom panel.

Comment: That is petty much what i do. I have a usercontrol which hosts a `flowLayoutPanel` inside that panel I load other controls. My question is: How can I add other controls on a different place than on the bottom? (I want them placed one above the bottom control:))

Comment: You should have a panel that isent flowLayoutPanel as the outermost panel, on that panel you add your flowLayoutPanel and then your two other controls.